# Find consecutive dates in table (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I need to determine the most recent consecutive days a license plate has been recorded into a table. Plates may appear in table several times in a given day, but a inventory check is done at minimum once every 24 hours (to avoid 24hour "checkouts").

A day is NOT 24 hours to the report.  **12hr <= day <= 24hr** .  Ie - if a vehicle is in inventory at 8:00am, and stays until 8:00pm the following day (36hrs total) it would register as 2 days.

If a vehicle leaves inventory for greater than 25hrs than it is assumed the current stay is over and any further stay is a new one.

Only the most recent stay for any one LicensePlate should be reported.

Example Data:

```
LicensePlate |       TimeStamp     | Location
---------------------------------------------
abc123       | 1969-01-01 08:42:23 | West Lot   ---
abc123       | 1969-01-01 12:34:29 | West Lot      ---
abc123       | 1969-01-01 18:20:10 | West Lot         ---
abc123       | 1969-01-02 02:19:02 | West Lot             --- 2 Days Closed
abc123       | 1969-01-02 08:38:05 | West Lot         ---
abc123       | 1969-01-02 12:13:39 | West Lot      ---
abc123       | 1969-01-02 20:43:34 | West Lot   ---
123abc       | 1969-01-02 09:31:04 | South Lot  ---
123abc       | 1969-01-02 15:31:04 | South Lot     --- 1 Day (more than 12hr) Closed
123abc       | 1969-01-02 22:31:04 | South Lot  ---
abc123       | 1969-01-04 22:48:37 | North Lot  ---
abc123       | 1969-01-05 17:57:32 | North Lot     --- 4 Days (reported)
abc123       | 1969-01-06 14:12:48 | North Lot     --- 
abc123       | 1969-01-07 13:05:18 | North Lot  ---
123abc       | 1969-01-03 12:22:32 | East Lot   ---
123abc       | 1969-01-03 19:16:25 | East Lot      ---
123abc       | 1969-01-04 06:22:13 | East Lot         ---
123abc       | 1969-01-04 13:22:56 | East Lot         --- 3 Days (reported)
123abc       | 1969-01-05 11:22:32 | East Lot         ---
123abc       | 1969-01-06 08:22:44 | East Lot      ---
123abc       | 1969-01-06 12:22:08 | East Lot   ---
```

Generated Report would have the following data

```
LicensePlate |     EnteredDate     |  Location   |  DaysIn
----------------------------------------------------------
abc123       | 1969-01-04 12:48:37 |  North Lot  |     4
123abc       | 1969-01-03 12:22:32 |  North Lot  |     3
```

Actual table is different in schema, just need a pointer of how I should accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do exactly what I needed to do.

```
SELECT Plate, Begin, StayEnd, Loc, DATEDIFF(StayEnd, Begin) As Count FROM (SELECT 
Plate, Begin, max(`TimeStamp`) AS StayEnd, Loc FROM 
(SELECT inven_table.*,
@f:=CONVERT(IF(@c<=>Plate AND @r<=>Loc AND DATEDIFF(`TimeStamp`, @d)<=1, @f, 
`TimeStamp`), DATETIME) AS Begin,
@c:=Plate, @d:=`TimeStamp`, @r:=Loc
FROM inven_table JOIN (SELECT @c:=NULL) AS init 
ORDER BY Plate,`TimeStamp`, Loc) AS t WHERE Plate = 'XXXXXX' GROUP BY Begin) As C 
GROUP By Begin ORDER BY StayEnd DESC
```